# SQL: return values that don't match as NULL

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have an array of data taken from a CSV file of around 900 records. I have a query which checks the data in the array against records in a database. The query returns all the items from the database that are found/match the data in the array

However, I'd still like the records from the array that don't match the database to be included in the results e.g. with a null value or something like that

I've searched for a solution but nothing seems to match my situation

Any help is appreciated

```
SELECT U.address, 
               U.postcode, 
               M.member_id 
FROM members M
LEFT JOIN ... On ...
WHERE 
U.address LIKE :address
U.postcode = :postcode 
... So on
```

Using pdo prepared statement

Comment: None can help if you don't show your code...

Comment: show you query ..

Comment: Create a temporary table from the CSV and perform a `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: Added query example. I also cannot create a table for this database

Comment: @cheesycoder CD001 suggested a _temporary_ table.

Comment: Yes and I can't do that

Comment: can't you give the user this is running under permission to create temp tables? Does that present a problem? Not the same as creating real ones.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using a union, the second part would be to create a dummy record which has something to show it's from the CSV, but it has a null member_id...

```
SELECT U.address, U.postcode, M.member_id 
    FROM members M
    LEFT JOIN ... On ...
UNION
SELECT * 
    FROM ( SELECT :address, :postcode, null ) as TEMP
    WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 
                            FROM members M1
                            LEFT JOIN ... On ...)
```

It's not ideal, it may be easier to process a record at a time and check the record count for each select.